# Is it possible to return to a servlet caller from jsp?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

Is it possible to return to a caller servlet from jsp?

This is how my program goes.

ServletA ---calls----> JSP (has form)-----go back with values-------->ServletA

Its a loop.

I'm thinking of putting the files in my datastore but it will cost too many queries so I'm looking for a shortcut.

Thanks in advance for ideas. :)

Comment: set `action="servletA"` of `<form>` in JSP.

Comment: I do not get your question. What do you mean by 'files', the JSPs? Of course the scenario you described will work, didn't you try it?